# how does spring cloud zuul get request parameter when content type is multipart/form-data?

Tags: netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I need to upload file through `zuul` to my application, the content type is multipart/form-data, but I have some other parameters in the request.

So how can I get the parameters in the `zuul`?

I want to get the token to check the request is valid or not.

I've tried `"request.getParameter("token");"`,but it does not work.

Comment: Please post all the relevant code you used attempting to solve this issue yourself. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

if you Get `request` through

```java
RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
HttpServletRequest request = context.getRequest();
```

the call `request.getParameter("token");` It does not return any valid values

This away may solve this issue

```java
HttpServletRequestWrapper httpServletRequestWrapper = (HttpServletRequestWrapper) request;
String token = httpServletRequestWrapper.getRequest().getParameter("token");
```

ps:

I suggest you check the request type first before getting the value.by this way

```java
String requestType = request.getContentType().split(";")[0];
if(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE.equls(requestType)){
    HttpServletRequestWrapper httpServletRequestWrapper = (HttpServletRequestWrapper) request;
    token = httpServletRequestWrapper.getRequest().getParameter("token");
}
```